# need to paste info in the next blank space

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

With this code it will copy the data and paste it on the appropriate corresponding tab that the name belongs to, but when I run it again for the next set of data it over write the last data. I am not sure how to add the verbiage to paste to the next empty row

```
    Dim c As Range, namesRng As Range
    Dim name As Variant

    With Worksheets("DRIVERS") '<--| reference "DRIVERS" worskheet
        Set namesRng = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)) '<--| set the range of "drivers" in column "a" starting from row 4 down to last not empty row
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<--| instance a 'Dictionary' object
        For Each c In namesRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through "drivers" range cells with text content only
            .Item(c.Value) = c.Value '<--| build the unique list of names using dictionary key
        Next
        Set namesRng = namesRng.Resize(namesRng.Rows.Count + 1).Offset(-1) '<--| resize the range of "names" to have a "header" cell (not a name to filter on) in the first row
        For Each name In .Keys '<--| loop through dictionary keys, i.e. the unique names list
            FilterNameAndCopyToWorksheet namesRng, name '<--| filter on current name and copy to corresponding worksheet
        Next
    End With '<--| release the 'Dictionary' object
End Sub

Sub FilterNameAndCopyToWorksheet(rangeToFilter As Range, nameToFilter As Variant)
    Dim destsht As Worksheet

    Set destsht = Worksheets(nameToFilter) '<--| set the worksheet object corresponding to passed name
    With rangeToFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=nameToFilter
        Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Copy destsht.Cells(destsht.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When asking a code-related question, it is always wise to add a tag for the specific language you're using. *copy* and *paste* are pretty much useless on their own. Please [edit] to include the appropriate language tag (excel-vba, it would appear) to your question. You should also explain how the code you've posted isn't working for you. As it reads now, it's a *please write the code for me* post, and we're not a code writing service. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Ken first time I have ever asked in a forum. I will correct the verbage

Comment: No problem. Word of advice, though - this isn't a forum, and people don't like it when you refer to it as one. *Forum* implies a social site with discussions, and this is absolutely not such a site. This is strictly a question and answer site. You may want to spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages.

Comment: ok thanks I will do that

Comment: Great support Ken.

Comment: You should always add error handling when working with `SpecialCells`.    `Range.Copy` only copies visible rows in a filtered range.  `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` isn't needed in your code.  @Sixthsense has the correct answer.  You should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
destsht.Cells(destsht.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)
```

In the above code Just add offset() in the end.

```
destsht.Cells(destsht.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```